# Storing results in a recursive function/ BST

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, traversal

I'm writing a bst function that would store all the keys within a given range as a String:

```
 String rangeToString(TreeNode root,int low, int high, String result){
  if(root==null) return ""; 
  if(root.key>low)) rangeToString(root.leftChild, low, high,result);
  if(root.key>=low && root.key.<=high) result+=root.key;
  if(root.key<high) rangeToString(root.rightChild,low,high,result);
  return result;
```

}

I'm basically doing an inorder traversal, adding values to the string when they're in range.
At the moment it returns a string that only contains the root key.
I know the problem is in my return statements, but I just can't seem to get how to implement the function without them. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want to include a return on your recursion calls, since you are returning the results of your recursions:

```
String rangeToString(TreeNode root,int low, int high, String result){
  if(root==null) return ""; 
  if(root.key>low)) return rangeToString(root.leftChild, low, high,result);
  if(root.key>=low && root.key.<=high) result+=root.key;
  if(root.key<high) return rangeToString(root.rightChild,low,high,result);
  return result;
}
```

I am suspicious of your conditions, so I would spend some time examining those...  In fact, the return on the recursions are making an assumption about the structure of your conditions.

Also, one way of gathering parameters that's pretty intuitive is to use tail recursion and accumulate your results in your parameters.

You can read more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

The key is that you are using your parameters themselves to gather the results, and when your function is done, you return your parameters (the ones that accumulate the results).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass into your arguments a supplentary "accumulated up to now" list of strings (say you name it `curlist`). then when you return you return this `curlist argument + .Add(your found key for this recursion level)` and in the places you recursively call the fonction (`rangeToString`) you concatenate the result to the current list `curlist` (using Append or whatever).

pseudo code:

```
list<string> myRecursiveFunc(some args, list<string> curlist)
{
   if (recursConditionOK)
      curlist = curlist.Append(myRecusriveFunc, curlist);
   return curlist;
}
```